# Constructing an Algebraically Closed Space

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How would one construct the simplest -- or canonical, if a canonical construction exists -- countably infinite algebraic closure of the natural numbers?

Comment: what do you mean by algebraic closure of the natural numbers? and why did you tag this as 'constructive-mathematics'? how constructive do you want the construction to be?

Comment: 1) A countable set constructed from the natural numbers (in a similar way to how the reals are constructed from rationals or the rationals from integers).

Comment: 2) Because I didn't know what "constructive-mathematics" meant, but I was talking about a construction so maybe it fits?

Comment: 3) I don't know how to answer this..

Comment: By convention, "algebraic closure" is something you do to fields, and $\mathbb{N}$ is not even a ring (it is a semiring). You might be interested in the algebraic integers, which are in a suitable sense the "algebraic closure" of the integers (but this is not how they are usually described): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer

Comment: @IttayWeiss Feel free to edit this any way you like to make it more easily understandable.

Comment: Constructive mathematics is not (really) about constructions; it is about e.g. avoiding the axiom of choice, that kind of thing. (That's relevant here because in general it requires some choice to construct algebraic closures.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Those look like what I was looking for.  How would one construct them starting from the integers?

Comment: Usually one first constructs the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ using a standard construction of algebraic closures of fields (see e.g. any textbook that covers Galois theory), then looks for the algebraic integers inside this. The standard construction involves some use of the axiom of choice; for $\mathbb{Q}$ it is possible to avoid this (e.g. by looking at the algebraic numbers inside $\mathbb{C}$), but I believe the statement that the algebraic closure is unique is still independent of ZF. So you don't know that you've constructed "the" algebraic closure without some choice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there no way (or no known way) to construct the set of algebraic integers directly from the integers?

Comment: @user: I mean, you can do it by modifying the construction of the algebraic closure suitably. But all of the same issues remain. It's essentially the same construction.

Answer (score 1):

One construction is simply to take all algebraic elements of $\mathbb{C}$ But a more general method is to enumerate all polynomials with integer coefficients, $p_n(x)$ and define $F_{n+1}$ to be $F_n(\alpha_1, \ldots ,\alpha_k)$ where $\alpha_1, \ldots ,\alpha_k$ are the roots of $p_{n+1}(x)$. Then $F=\bigcup F_n$ will be algebraically closed. For if $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$ there is some $n$ such that $\beta$ is algebraic over $F_n$ and so the extension $F_n(\beta)/F_0$ is finite dimensional and so $\beta$ is algebraic over $F_0$ and will have been included in the construction.